# Why do I get: "celeryctl: command not found", do I have to install celeryctl?

Tags: python, celery

When I run
`celeryctl help` I get:

```
-bash: celeryctl: command not found
```

Do I have to install it? I do have `celery` installed.
The docs do not say anything about installing it. Tried `pip install celeryctl`, no luck.

Comment: I think `celeryctl` was deprecated and removed a long time ago https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/dec8a141a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what used to be called `celeryctl` is just called `celery` now. When I `pip install celery` and run `celery --version` I see 5.0.5. All the docs online that reference `celeryctl` are for much older releases of celery (2.x.x).

The daemon that `celeryctl` interacts with, `celeryd`, appears to have never been renamed. I think should have a `celeryd` executable and a `celery` executable and those are all you're supposed to have these days.

OP adds: "I found that you can get the same functionality as `celeryctl` by typing in the CLI: `celery -A proj [celeryctl command]`."

Comment: Great answer, it led me in the right direction. I found that you can get the same functionality as ```celeryctl``` by typing in the CLI: ```celery -A proj [celeryctl command]```. Please, include this in your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov sure, I will update my answer. Fyi, you should also be able to edit my comment before accepting it if you would like to. :)

Comment: Thanks. No, I'm not able to edit it, I tried before accepting.

Comment: Ah interesting, my bad. maybe you can't do that on your own questions.